# Why does not transfer list of the model that i defined in the web service as a output of method?

Tags: java, web-services

I created a method in web service that output method is "list of model", but when call web service in client side output is "obj".

model class is in the directory of model's web service.
settings is in the server config.

User-side and server-side programming is with me.
protocol is soap.

change server-config file, Serializable model

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding()
public class WebsiteWebService {  

/**
 * voip-
 * return list of Customer Activity Report
 * @param oid_contract
 * @return A list of activities report activities
 */
@WebMethod
public List<RActivity_history> Activity_history(Long oid_contract) {
    SaleServiceWebsite saleServiceWebsite3 = new SaleServiceWebsite();
    try {
        return saleServiceWebsite3.Activity_history(oid_contract);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

in server-config.wsdd:
   `<beanMapping qname="ns:RActivity_history" xmlns:ns="RActivity_history" languageSpecificType="java:crm.web_service.model.RActivity_history"/>`

in client-sid:
i expect the method output to be `"List<RActivity_history>"` but the actual method output is "ArrayOf_xsd_anyType".

Comment: There is a typo in your `GetImportantFeildFromDB` call, are you aware of this?

Comment: Yes thanks was corrected from your note, it was a mistake